# How to add numbers in a list, if some of the numbers are appended from user input?

Tags: python

I made a simple working craps game with point and everything, but I wanted to implement betting. The idea is that the player will input a bet amount and the amount will be deducted from the player wallet and added onto the bet. Afterwards if the player won, the bet is returned including the winnings.

I set up a variable that takes user input, I then append the variable to a list. Afterwards I set up two other variables that add everything in the lists together by: sum().

CODE:

```
bet_numbers = []
bet = sum(bet_numbers)
user_input = input("How much would you like to bet?")
bet_numbers.append(user_input)
user_input_2 = input("How much would you like to bet?")
bet_numbers.append(user_input_2)
print(bet_numbers)
print(bet)
```

for example

```
user_input = input("How much would you like to bet?")
200
user_input = input("How much would you like to bet?")
300
result:
[200,300]
0
```

Comment: On the second bet, wouldn't you need to append userinput2

Comment: Hello, you have call `sum(bet_numbers)` everytime you want to get the sum of updated numbers...

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.  Your posted code does not produce the given output, as it never uses the second input value.  You make no attempt to `sum` the bets, as the only call is before there are any bets in the list.  I'm a little unclear on what output you expect; tracing the problems as *you* see them would help.

Comment: Python is an imperative language, so statements need to be in the right order to be effective.

Comment: @Parkofadown Yes, sorry, I just edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bet = sum(int(b) for b in bet_numbers)
print(bet)
```

You've never summed up `bet_number` after they were populated. Move the `sum` just before printing `bet`

Also, you're taking `str` inputs, so you need to convert them to `int` before summing

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some errors

1. You are summing an empty list, because you call `bet = sum(bet_numbers)` right after you define `bet_numbers = []`, and `sum([])=0`
2. Even if you were to call `bet = sum(bet_numbers)` after asking for bets, it wouldn't have worked since your elements of `bet_numbers` list will be strings, and you cannot sum strings. I tried it below and you can see it won't work

```
In [2]: sum(['2'+'2'])                                                          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-b6e099608f0b> in <module>
----> 1 sum(['2'+'2'])

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

3. You are calling the same two lines twice, whereas you could use a for loop

Taking all this in consideration, your code can be much simplified as

```
bet_numbers = []

#Run a for loop twice
for i in range(2):
    #Ask for user input, convert to int and apppend to list
    user_input = int(input("How much would you like to bet?"))
    bet_numbers.append(user_input)

#Sum all items in bet_numbers lis
bet = sum(bet_numbers)
print(bet)
```

A sample output will be

```
How much would you like to bet?20
How much would you like to bet?30
50
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the order of declaration bet is equal to 0 as it correctly did a sum of the bet_numbers items.

The solution would be to put `bet = sum(bet_numbers)` after asking the inputs from the players